# iOS controls on iPad specific screen sizes

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6

I have a fundamental question that I would like to get addressed. I'm almost done with my universal app and I was told that I need to specifically customize the UI controls for iPad screens (e.g) labels, buttons. So, for example, I have the following code in viewDidLoad event in one of my xibs.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    [_lblRandomDisplay setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue" size:100]];
}
else
{
    [_lblRandomDisplay setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue" size:250]];
}
```

Here _lblRandomDisplay is UILabel IBOutlet property and I increase the font for iPad and reduce it for iPhone. Is this the way to approach the iPad screens or does iOS automatically scale the screen when viewed on iPad?. As a side note, I have named the xib filenames as filename~iphone.xib and filename~ipad.xib and it loads correctly based on the device selected in the simulator.

In those lines, I have a Settings screen (not using the Settings bundle) using UITableViews that I have designed for iPhone and programmatically load data from NSArray. When loaded on iPad using the settings~ipad.xib (copied the controls from settings~iphone.xib), I haven't adjusted the row height specifically for iPad to make it look bigger. The screen shows OK on the iPad but it looks smaller. Is this the right approach or what is the best way to approach this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice that you have been given, to customise UIControls for screen size, seems wrong. UIControl sizes, and text sizes in general, should remain the same on all devices. These items are designed in sizes appropriate for readability and touchability, neither of which has any relationship to screen size.

iOS is designed with this in mind. If you make a universal project with iPad and iPhone xibs or storyboards, you will find that user interface widgets are the same pixel/point size regardless of the device (I am ignoring Retina/non-retina distinctions here for simplicity). For example, the default size of a standard button is 73 x 43 with a font size of 15pt in both cases. A Navigation Bar is 44 px/points high on both devices. This is as it should be. If we assume that reading distance on an iPhone, or an iPad mini, or an iPad is approximately the same, then there is no reason to adjust text size. The idea of redesigning for the iPad is really that you can get *more* information on one screen, not a bigger version of the *same* information.

There are two circumstances in which iOS "scales the screen":

- is if you create an iPhone-only app and run it on an iPad. Then there is a user option to run it at double size. In this case everything including font sizes are scaled up, but this is done by pixel-doubling, so the effect is a big blur. Take a look at it - and you will understand that this is precisely the reason why you should *not* design in this way.
- if you use a single xib/storyboard for both iPhone and iPad, and rely on autolayout (ios6+) or autoresizing masks (ios5-) to auto-adjust the layout for different screen sizes. This method can -depending on your settings - proportionally resize image content of views, but will not dynamically resize text content, if you wanted to do that you would have to adjust in code. This is not a good way of designing an app anyway, it is better to make a dedicated design for iPhone and for iPad in separate xib/storyboards as you have done.

I expect when you say the iPad "looks smaller" you mean, the UI appears smaller as it gets lost on the larger screen... but the answer is not to just enlarge the size of your data, it is to reconsider your layout to fit more data on each screen. That is why with the iPad Apple provided the SplitViewController and introduced the pattern of the Container ViewController.

I wonder if you are also raising a related, but separate issue of proportional sizing of views for graphic design purposes (you mention font sizes of 100 and 250pt, not usual sizes for UI controls labels). You may want the *look* of your app to scale with the screen, a bit like the so-called fluid web design approach to variable window sizes. So for example you may have a graphic device based on a huge letter 'A' that fills your iphone screen, and want that letter to similarly fill you ipad screen. In this case you may need to set font sizes as in your code example.

You are certainly doing the right thing by *not* altering the row height of your table cells for the different devices, but for the larger screen you can of course make your table height larger, and accomodate more table cells in your view.

All of these comments are a bit general, as you haven't posted enough detail of your problem. It often helps to post a picture or two...